# Access Windows GPU in Boot2Docker

Tags: windows, audio, docker, boot2docker, pyaudio

Is there a way to work with the Windows GPU in Boot2Docker? In particular, I'm aiming to be able to record audio with pyaudio inside of a Docker container. I know that when running on Linux, you can use the --device flag to mount /dev/snd/ appropriately; however, I need this to be able to run on Windows.

Is there a way to access the sound card from inside a Boot2Docker VM? Or is this something that requires a separate Linux VM?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: DId you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Unfortunately not... I actually ended up switching to Linux as my primary dev machine.